# Render dynamic images in ScrollView without Height and Width

Tags: react-native

Semi-new to React Native and i'm having an issue...

I'm trying to add dynamic images in a scrollView with 3 columns of images and multiple rows. Like in the image

Sample view of the screen :

[image]

the trick is i don't have to give height and width for images as for different sizes of screens it will become odd.

For rendering 3 images in 1 row I'm using this

```
<ImageBackground
          source = {{uri: *image_url*}}
          style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
<ImageBackground>
```

I tried scrollView and view with flex properties but it will auto adjust sizes of the rows and scrollView doesn't work.

```
    <View style = {{flex: 16, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle = {{paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: 0, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0}}>
        <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', padding: 5,  alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
          {
            row_1.map((image) => {
              return image
            })
          }
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

row_1 is the array of the images I want to display in 1 row.

I also saw documentation for native which says that for dynamic images one has to use height and width.

Is there any way for this?

Comment: Have you tried using % sizes? If you have them each wrapped in a `View`, and the `View` is already adjusting size through `flex`, you could try giving each `Image` `width: '100%'`

Comment: @zaytrix i tried it and it doesn't change anything. Still the row size gets adjust and scrollView doesn't work.

Comment: Actually scroll view works but when i add many rows. Height of images of each rows keeps decreasing automatically